# Cocos2d-x 3.13.1: error with cocos run (Android)

Tags: android, c++, build, android-ndk, cocos2d-x

:-)

I moved to Cocos2d-x 3.13.1 from a couple of days (I moved from 3.12).
My game works great when compiled for Linux.
When however I try to execute my game on my Android device I get this:

```
drk@drk-pc ~/cocos2d-projects/SpaceRush $ cocos run -p android --android-studio
Building mode: debug
Using Android Studio project : /home/drk/cocos2d-projects/SpaceRush/proj.android-studio
running: '/home/drk/Android/Sdk/tools/android update project -t android-19 -p /home/drk/cocos2d-projects/SpaceRush/proj.android-studio/app'

Updated project.properties
Updated local.properties
Updated file /home/drk/cocos2d-projects/SpaceRush/proj.android-studio/app/proguard-project.txt
Building native...
NDK build mode: debug
running: '/home/drk/Android/android-ndk-r12b/ndk-build -C /home/drk/cocos2d-projects/SpaceRush/proj.android-studio/app -j12 NDK_MODULE_PATH=/home/drk/cocos2d-projects/SpaceRush/proj.android-studio/../cocos2d:/home/drk/cocos2d-projects/SpaceRush/proj.android-studio/../cocos2d/cocos:/home/drk/cocos2d-projects/SpaceRush/proj.android-studio/../cocos2d/external NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION=4.9 NDK_DEBUG=1'

make: ingresso nella directory "/home/drk/cocos2d-projects/SpaceRush/proj.android-studio/app"
/home/drk/Android/android-ndk-r12b/build/core/build-module.mk:34: *** missing separator.  Arresto.
make: uscita dalla directory "/home/drk/cocos2d-projects/SpaceRush/proj.android-studio/app"
Error running command, return code: 2.
```

I don't know how to solve this problem, I'm not an Android build expert!
I tried to compile both with NDK 11c and 12b.

Thanks for your help

Comment: I solved my problem with NDK 10e

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try a different NDK, possible 10e.